# Order by relevance based on multiple conditions using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am having an issue while using order by based on multiple conditions.
User with most filled information should show up top and then the one's with less filled information.

```
 $users = User::where('status',1)  
 ->withCount('reviews')
 ->with('reviews','about')
 ->orderByRaw("CASE WHEN is_native != '0' AND photo != '' THEN 0  ELSE 1 END")// how i can match the about us relationship value here? means if user have added about intro then it should come first and reviews count? 
 ->paginate(10);
```

Here is my About Relationship on User

```
public function about()
{
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserAbout', 'user_id')->select('about');
}
```

NOTE: i am trying to do it with CASE, if there is any other good option you can please point out that.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this means that you have to orderby about's count and then by review count, that will get the result you want:

```
 $users = User::where('status',1)  
 ->withCount(['reviews','about'])
 ->with('reviews','about')
 ->orderByRaw('about_count desc,reviews_count desc')
 ->paginate(10);
```

now user with 'about' will have `about_count=1` others will have `about_count =0`

Comment: Thank you.But what if i have to check if user has upload the photo to give it preference?

Comment: the 'photo ' is a column inside users' table?

Comment: Yes it's a column

Comment: then you can do something like:
->orderByRaw('users.photo, about_count desc,reviews_count desc')

Answer (score 0):

As @OMR suggested you can do that. But you don't need to use **raw Query**

```
$users = User::where('status',1)  
 ->withCount(['reviews','about'])
 ->with('reviews','about')
 ->orderBy('about_count','desc')
 ->orderBy('reviews_count','desc')
 ->paginate(10);
```